# STD Bad Alloc exception

Tags: c++, vector, bad-alloc

This program strictly reads only alphabets, and pushes back to the vector as so.
However the text file is just like any other text file.

I have encountered this STD bad alloc exception and is as follows.

```
char keyArray[5][5];

keyArray[0][1] = 'a';
keyArray[0][2] = 'b';
keyArray[0][3] = 'c';
keyArray[0][4] = 'd';
keyArray[0][5] = 'e';
keyArray[1][1] = 'f';
keyArray[1][2] = 'g';
keyArray[1][3] = 'h';
keyArray[1][4] = 'i';
keyArray[1][5] = 'k';
keyArray[2][1] = 'l';
keyArray[2][2] = 'm';
keyArray[2][3] = 'n';
keyArray[2][4] = 'o';
keyArray[2][5] = 'p';
keyArray[3][1] = 'q';
keyArray[3][2] = 'r';
keyArray[3][3] = 's';
keyArray[3][4] = 't';
keyArray[3][5] = 'u';
keyArray[4][1] = 'v';
keyArray[4][2] = 'w';
keyArray[4][3] = 'x';
keyArray[4][4] = 'y';
keyArray[4][5] = 'z';


ifstream readFile;
vector<char> paddedVector;
char c;
int number_of_chars = 0;
readFile.open ("test.txt", ifstream::in);
while(  !readFile.eof() )
{
    if(readFile.peek() == -1)
        break;
    c = readFile.get();
    if(!isalpha(c))
        continue;

    if(c != '\n') //bad alloc here
    {
        ++number_of_chars;
        paddedVector.push_back(c); //std bad alloc happens here
    }
}
```

Please kindly advise.

*EDIT* When i took away the keyArray portion, it works fine. why is it so? what am i doing it incorrectly here?

Comment: What is the size of the file?

Comment: @Shahbaz, 1kb only. :(

Comment: Funny, your code works fine here. What are you hiding for us? :)

Comment: Haha, exactly as @WouterHuysentruit said, there is something else going on in your code that you're not showing us.

Comment: silly mistake again, thank you all for pointing that out. sigh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem are the following 5 lines:

```
keyArray[?][5] = '?';
```

where you are indexing out of the boundaries of your `keyArray` array. It has probably overwritten an internal pointer in the `paddedVector` object. In turn when the vector tries to (re)allocate memory, you get this exception because `delete[]` cannot understand where that address came from.

---

Note that for the same reason you started your first index from `0`, you should also start your second index from `0`! Therefore, both indices should be in the range `[0, 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char keyArray[5][5];
// ...
keyArray[4][5] = 'z';
```

The above writes beyond the end of the array. Valid indexes for `keyArray` are `keyArray[0..4][0..4]`. Your program is in undefined behaviour land.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly addressing the inner arrays.  They are also 0 based, so the format should be

```
keyArray[0][0] = 'a'
.
.
.
keyArray[4][4] = 'z'
```